# To-Do List App with Sync, Repeating To-Dos

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a To-Do list application with with following features:

- **Due dates**
- **Notes**
- **Sync to a cloud or web-based service where changes can be made**
- **Able to repeat to-dos by due date and last-completed date**
- Prioritization
- Groups / Filters / Folders such as Business, Personal, School
- Badge for items due today
- Projects (which incorporate other to-do items)

Can anyone recommend a to-do app with this functionality (especially the first 4 bolded items)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toodledo (the online to-do service) also has a companion [iPhone App](http://www.toodledo.com/info/iphone.php).  This app has:

- Due-dates for each item
- Notes for each item
- sync to Toodledo service
- Repeatable to-dos
- Prioritization
- Groups
- Application badge
- Projects (if you are a "Pro" yearly subscriber)

It's not as pretty as 2Do, but it is doing everything I need it to.  My only complaint is that the App Badge is not always accurate, even if I'm not editing tasks on the Toodledo site.

Answer (score 4):

## [2Do](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/2do-tasks-done-in-style/id303656546?mt=8)

has all the features that you require (and more):

- Due dates ✓
- Notes ✓
- Sync to a cloud or web-based service where changes can be made ✓ (Dropbox, iCloud and other)
- Able to repeat to-dos by due date and last-completed date ✓
- Prioritization ✓
- Groups / Filters / Folders such as Business, Personal, School ✓
- Badge for items due today (tab for today)
- Projects (which incorporate other to-do items) ✓

[image]           [image]

[[pictures](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/2do-tasks-done-in-style/id303656546?mt=8)]

Comment: 2Do has all the features, and I used it for a while.  But in the past month it started losing my repeating/due-date items, which is totally unacceptable for how much I rely on my to-do list.

Comment: @jmlumpkin I hope you do not mind my radical edit. I wanted to make your answer to be more direct towards the question.

Comment: awesome edit, thanks. I wanted to do more but their site is so disorganized was hard to explicitly call out each piece.

Answer (score 2):

[Todo by Appigo](http://itunes.apple.com/app/todo/id282778557?mt=8) does everything you request:

- Due dates *Yes*
- Notes *Yes, per task and per project*
- Sync to a cloud or web-based service where changes can be made *Yes, sync with toodledo, icloud, dropbox, or a few other methods*
- Able to repeat to-dos by due date and last-completed date *Yes*
- Prioritization *Yes*
- Groups / Filters / Folders such as Business, Personal, School *Yes*
- Badge for items due today *Yes, and overdue items*
- Projects (which incorporate other to-do items) *Yes - project contain subtasks*

There's also an iPad version, and a desktop app, and they all sync to each other using toodledo, dropbox, or icloud.

[image]

Comment: I feel like a shill, but I've been using this for some time and it's very, very nice.

Answer (score 1):

[Remember The Milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/) (RTM) does what you want. However the notes aren't as easy as I would like in the iOS app.

Comment: Sadly, Remember The Milk does not do the last request of projects (which incorporate other to-do items), other than that I really like RTM.

Answer (score 1):

[OmniFocus for iPhone](https://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnifocus-iphone/) meets all but the web-based service criterion (there is a [MacOS X companion application](https://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnifocus/) which came first).  If you are away from all your iOS/Mac devices, you're stuck.

I've used [Remember the Milk](https://www.rememberthemilk.com/), [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/), [Toodledo](http://www.toodledo.com/) (synced with [ToDo](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/todo/id282778557?mt=8)), and a half-dozen others - OmniFocus is the best, hands down.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a web-sync option for OmniFocus, which is important for my when I'm working on a PC.  Also, it's so expensive, especially the Mac App.

Comment: After looking at all of the options I could find and paying for Remember The Milk ($25) and 2Do ($10) I finally bought OmniFocus ($80 Mac app and $20 iOS app) and am mostly happy. It does everything you want except "Sync to a cloud or web-based service where changes can be made".

Answer (score 1):

I swear by [Awesome Note](http://www.bridworks.com/anote/en/iphone/features/index.php) and would be lost without it.

It does all the things you mentioned on your list (with the possible exception of projects). You can sync with Google Docs and [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/). The only thing I'd personally like to see, which may or may not bother you, is an Mac version so I can edit my todo's whilst I'm at my computer.

There's also a free [trial version](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/awesome-note-lite-to-do-diary/id330265490?mt=8) on the app store.

[image]

Comment: I have Awesome Note, and it's a super note-taking application.  But it's complicated to use as a to-do app for me, and I can't figure out how to get it to show an app badge of # of items due today.

Comment: @KatieK I know what you mean, it does take a bit of getting used to. But once you do its, er, awesome :) Anyway, to get badges to show, click the gear icon in the bottom left of Awesome Note's home screen, then click "To-do Settings", then "Badge Count". The best you can do is "Overdue + Today" though. You'll also have to switch on the Badge App Icon in the Notification Center too. Apologies if you already knew some, or all of that.

Answer (score 1):

[Wunderkit](http://get.wunderkit.com/) has everything you need, and more. (I personally use its stripped-down version, [Wunderlist](http://www.6wunderkinder.com/wunderlist/), for personal tasks - make sure you check it out as well.) Wunderkit is a perfect tool for collaboration (sharing tasks and workspaces, commenting, tracking team progress), but also works flawlessly for personal task management.

Here are some of the features (I think these cover each and every requirement of yours):

- Workspaces (that is, separate spaces for projects)
- Tasks (tags, assignees, due dates, recurring tasks, comments, starring)
- Notification-type badges for tasks due today
- Notes (also with tags)
- Syncing between apps
- Available for Mac OS X, iPhone, and as a web app

I expect the app to be available on more devices soon. I base this assumption on the fact that the before-mentioned Wunderlist is available on iOS, Android, Blackberry, WinPhone, Mac OS X, Windows, and Linux.

Oh, and the best part: **it's wonderfully designed, and it's free**.

[image: Wundekit]

Comment: cannot recommend it enough!

Comment: Wunderlist doesn't seem to have any functionality for repeating to-dos.  I didn't write this as a requirement, but Wunderkit wanted me to sign up for an account before using it, and I didn't want to do that.

Comment: Wunderlist does not have recurring tasks, Wunderkit does. And talking about getting an account - your priority feature is cloud syncing with online access. You *need* an account for that.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Wrike](http://www.wrike.com/) (also in [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wrike-project-management/id568975446)), and would recommend it as a great productivity app. It has everything you mentioned:

- You can create tasks with and without due dates and prioritize them on your list with drag-and-drop;
- Task description can be easily used as a notepad – you can overview changes in chronological order which is handier than taking separate notes;
- Personally I keep my company’s projects together with personal to-do lists in Wrike. You can group your tasks into folders and subfolders, and include one task into multiple folders;
- There are filters for sorting your tasks by due date, completion date, and more;
- In web version you also can create custom widgets with tasks due today (or basically any other criterion), and Wrike will show you an up-to-date task list on the dashboard once you log in;
- The service integrates with GMail and Dropbox, so you can combine it with whatever tools you already use for your work.

Comment: Can you please add a link pointing to the website or app in the Store? Also, in case you are somehow involved with the software you are describing here, please be open about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used 2Do, Clear, Any.DO and finally decided to create Q (kyoo) out of frustration with all of the above for lacking features I needed or having too many features I had absolutely no need for.

Comment: Can you please describe whether and how your app fulfils the requirements stated in the question?

Answer (score -4):

I would recommend adding Must Do Today to the list. It's a great app, simple and easy to use.
Must Do Today helps you organize your busy day.

http://mustdotoday.com/

Comment: Please have a look at the FAQ, especially the part about self-promotion. To make the answer more useful can you please describe what makes the app so great and how it matches the requirements listed in the question?